# Python pandas number frequency

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a csv file with two specific columns. One is a list of numbers separated by spaces. The second is one number.

Using pandas, I'm loading in the file but trying to convert the numbers from strings to integers. So far I have this code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file)
data['col 0'] = data['col 0'].str.split(' ')
```

I don't know how to convert the col 0 array of strings to an array of ints. the function .astype keeps throwing an array error.

Comment: Take out your second question and put it into a separate one, please ask one question per post. Also, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If the "col 0" is like "0 1 2 3" and if you wanted the column to become like "0123" you can use .replace() method to replace " "(space) with "" (empty string).

```
df['col 0'] = df['col 0'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:x.replace(" ", ""))
```

As @coldspeed stated please divide your question into two parts.

To convert the str type back to int just use astype(np.int)

Comment: I want it to look like [0, 1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is turn a list of strings into a list of ints, this way works:

```
d = {'col1': ["1 2 3 4 5 6 7"], 'col2': [3]}
df_example = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_example.col1 = df_example.col1.apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x.split(" "))))
```

You then have a list of ints as demonstrated by

```
df_example.col1[0]
out: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[x+1 for x in df_example.col1[0]]
out: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```